# Ruby on Rails: split string into hash and insert it to a json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model that looks something like:

```
  :created_at => Tue, 06 Jun 2017 15:34:32 UTC +00:00,
  :updated_at => Tue, 06 Jun 2017 15:34:35 UTC +00:00,
     :metrics => {
                "metric_a" => 10756,
                "metric_b" => "",
                "metric_c" => 6.67267607666759
},
  :status => "working"
```

With the  `metrics` field as a json.

And I want to split a string such as:

```
"Home/Personal Finance=37.00%=55,Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development=13.77%=48,News=8.64%=45,Arts/Television=5.23%=42,Arts/Music=2.99%=39,News/Current Events=2.66%=38,Society/Issues=2.47%=38,Computers/Internet/On the Web=2.46%=38,Business/Investing=1.76%=36,Society=1.70%=36"
```

To be named `categories` under the `metrics` field so that each category will hold two numbers, the percentage and the number that follows it.
So in the example above it would look like:

```
  :created_at => Tue, 06 Jun 2017 15:34:32 UTC +00:00,
  :updated_at => Tue, 06 Jun 2017 15:34:35 UTC +00:00,
     :metrics => {
                "metric_a" => 10756,
                "metric_b" => "",
                "metric_c" => 6.67267607666759
                "categories" => {
            "Home/Personal Finance": [37.00,55],
            "Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development": [13.77,48],
            ...
            }

},
  :status => "working"
```

Basically I want to save the two numbers for each category (maybe there's a better way to store them by the way?).

Either way can split the string with `.split(",")` but what next?

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your string is always the same, you could do something like this to get the `"categories"` hash:

```
str = "Home/Personal Finance=37.00%=55,Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development=13.77%=48,News=8.64%=45,Arts/Television=5.23%=42,Arts/Music=2.99%=39,News/Current Events=2.66%=38,Society/Issues=2.47%=38,Computers/Internet/On the Web=2.46%=38,Business/Investing=1.76%=36,Society=1.70%=36"

str.split(",").each_with_object({}) do |line, categories|
  items = line.split("=")
  categories[items[0]] = [items[1].gsub("%", "").to_f, items[2].to_i]
end
```

Output:

```
{
  "Home/Personal Finance"=>[37.0, 55],
  "Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development"=>[13.77, 48],
  "News"=>[8.64, 45],
  "Arts/Television"=>[5.23, 42],
  "Arts/Music"=>[2.99, 39],
  "News/Current Events"=>[2.66, 38],
  "Society/Issues"=>[2.47, 38],
  "Computers/Internet/On the Web"=>[2.46, 38],
  "Business/Investing"=>[1.76, 36],
  "Society"=>[1.7, 36]
}
```

Comment: `each_with_object`, that's good! I'm going to have to study up on that one. Hey, so the reason I was going with `split_line.split('=').tap do |line_parts|` was because I was trying to avoid the `items = line.split("=")` assignment. I don't have a good reason for why I was trying to avoid it. Do you have any views on pros/cons of assignment? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: @jvillian That's good too, and seems more idiomatic. In fact i don't like that kind of assignments either (also without good reason), so i generally try to avoid them; but in this case it kept the code 1 line shorter and, arguably, easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Dang, Gerry, you're good!

I was going to say:

```
  str.split(',').inject({}) do |to_return, split_line|
    split_line.split('=').tap do |line_parts|
      to_return[line_parts[0]] = [line_parts[1].gsub('%','').to_f,line_parts[2].to_i]
    end
    to_return
  end
```

Output:

```
  {
    "Home/Personal Finance"=>[37.0, 55], 
    "Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development"=>[13.77, 48], 
    "News"=>[8.64, 45], 
    "Arts/Television"=>[5.23, 42], 
    "Arts/Music"=>[2.99, 39], 
    "News/Current Events"=>[2.66, 38], 
    "Society/Issues"=>[2.47, 38], 
    "Computers/Internet/On the Web"=>[2.46, 38], 
    "Business/Investing"=>[1.76, 36], 
    "Society"=>[1.7, 36]
  }
```

But, as always, yours is cleaner. I'm still learning!

Comment: Thanks (just learning too)! It _may_ look cleaner, but your's get the exact output OP's asking for (i still got to clean the `%`s).

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for this, or something like this:

```rb
str="Home/Personal Finance=37.00%=55,Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development=13.77%=48,News=8.64%=45,Arts/Television=5.23%=42,Arts/Music=2.99%=39,News/Current Events=2.66%=38,Society/Issues=2.47%=38,Computers/Internet/On the Web=2.46%=38,Business/Investing=1.76%=36,Society=1.70%=36"

categories = {}

str = str.split(',').each do |category|

    parts = category.split('=')

    # Parts:
    #   0: Home/Personal Finance
    #   1: 37.00%
    #   2: 55

    key = parts[0]
    first_number = Float(parts[1].gsub('%', ''))
    last_number = parts[2].to_i

    categories[key] = [first_number, last_number]

end
```

Comment: No regex in my example! I'm bad with them xD

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a good option here. Assuming that your *category names* will never have `=`, `%` or `,` as a character, you could do:

```
categories_string = "Home/Personal Finance=37.00%=55,Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development=13.77%=48,News=8.64%=45,Arts/Television=5.23%=42,Arts/Music=2.99%=39,News/Current Events=2.66%=38,Society/Issues=2.47%=38,Computers/Internet/On the Web=2.46%=38,Business/Investing=1.76%=36,Society=1.70%=36"

categories_string.scan(/(.+?)=(.+?)%=(.+?),/).map do |x,y,z|
  { x => [y.to_f, z.to_i] }
end.reduce Hash.new, :merge

#=> {"Home/Personal Finance"=>[37.0, 55], "Computers/Internet/Web Design and Development"=>[13.77, 48], "News"=>[8.64, 45], "Arts/Television"=>[5.23, 42], "Arts/Music"=>[2.99, 39], "News/Current Events"=>[2.66, 38], "Society/Issues"=>[2.47, 38], "Computers/Internet/On the Web"=>[2.46, 38], "Business/Investing"=>[1.76, 36]}
```